# Unicode character support for both android and iOS

Tags: android, ios

I am trying to support displaying content returned from a REST endpoint in both android and iOS apps.  I want to return a string that would look like this:

```
{"title":"This is my title with a superscript\u00B9"}
```

The UI should display the text and the superscript will be rendared like so:

This is my title with a superscript¹

This issue is that android supports unicode like this:
\u00B9
and iOS supports this:
\u{00B9}

Is there a standard way to return the unicode characters that both mobile apps can display?

Thanks

Comment: Why use any encoding? Why not put the actual `¹` in the JSON returned from the server? Then no one needs to decode anything.

Comment: And any JSON decoder (on iOS and Android) would decode  `\u00B9` properly. `\u{00B9}` is used for *string literals* and irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I did only test by manually setting a text view.  I didn't get to the point of returning JSON from an endpoint.  Thanks rmaddy, I will try that too.